# How to use conda develop to install a script with all it's depedencies (in development/editable mode)?

Tags: python, conda

I have installed in development mode with conda using `conda devlop`. Usually I do:

```
conda develop ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
```

and in that folder setup.py is at. I noticed that it didn't install the dependencies automatically in the `setup.py` file however and it seems to only add the path to the python sys path:

```
(synthesis) miranda9@draco3:~$ python -c "import sys; [print(p) for p in sys.path]"

/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python39.zip
/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9
/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
/home/miranda9/type-parametric-synthesis/src
```

what is the proper way to install all the dependencies with `conda develop` and what is the exact command(s) used?

Comment: I don't see anything in [the code](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/blob/cd761345ee4542eb19b989a1f44ff9cea457bdc2/conda_build/develop.py#L136) for *installing* the package (i.e., running `setup.py`) - it just links the folder into `site-packages`. That is, there is no way to do this with `conda-build develop`.

Comment: hi @merv thanks for that! Then how can I use another conda command to install dependencies in conjunction to when I am using `conda develop`. I still need the dependencies to be installed.

Comment: @CharlieParker there is no really clean way I know of. Conda really sucks in this regard. I think about the best you can do is actually install your package, so all the dependencies get installed, then do `conda remove --force` to force uninstall it without removing the dependencies, and then run `conda develop` after that to get an editable install.